# Runtime Error Multi-Processing Mutex - Process Sync

Tags: multithreading, winapi, process, multiprocessing, mutex

I am trying to solve the classic dining philosophers problem. The Dining Philosopher Problem states that K philosophers seated around a circular table with one chopstick between each pair of philosophers. There is one chopstick between each philosopher. A philosopher may eat if he can pickup the two chopsticks adjacent to him. One chopstick may be picked up by any one of its adjacent followers but not both. I am trying to solve this with multi processing which means that every chopstick is a mutex and every philosopher is a process.

```
HANDLE forks[NUMBER_OF_FORKS];

int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si[NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS]; // NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS is 5
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi[NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS]; // NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS is 5

    initForks(NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS); // The function initializing all the Mutexs

    std::string param;
    LPWSTR test;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS; i++)
    {
        ZeroMemory(&si[i], sizeof(si[i]));
        si[i].cb = sizeof(si[i]);
        ZeroMemory(&pi[i], sizeof(pi[i]));
        
        // Converting the param to LPWSTR(The param represent the number of the philosopher).
        param = std::to_string(i);
        test = ConvertString(param);

        if (!CreateProcess(L"..\\Debug\\Philosopher.exe", test, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si[i], &pi[i]))
        {
            std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS; i++)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi[i].hProcess, INFINITE);
    }
}
```

At line 17 when I am using the CreateProcess function I am getting this Error:
[showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0wW8.png)

Can someone help me spot the problem? Thank you for help guys!

Comment: There are instructions on the dialog. Read them, carefully.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from the image,

```
Expression : _p !- nullptr
```

You did not initialize the `test` variable, try this,

```
LPWSTR test = new WCHAR[100];
memset(test, NULL, 200);
...
```

Or,

```
 std::string param;
 WCHAR test[100];
 param = std::to_string(i);
 mbstowcs(test, param.c_str(), param.size() + 1);  //Converts a multibyte character string from the array whose first element is pointed to by src to its wide character representation.
```